# Как HTML текст сохранить в Word с форматированием?

Tags: c#, .net, office, ms-word

Имеется текст из HTML, где присутствуют теги форматирования(жирнота, курсив и т п).

Как это можно сохранить в Word без потери форматирования?

Comment: Это подходит к вашему вопросу? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31287/how-do-insert-html-into-word-document

Comment: Только очень желательно указать о какой формате идёт речь. doc или docx?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Docx=> можно юзать OpenXml

Comment: Код по ссылке вам помог?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, пока не тестировал, но было бы неплохо, если бы расставили в нем комментарии. Не совсем понятно, что в некоторых местах происходит.

Comment: В ближайшее время вряд ли смогу (точно не сегодня). Главное уточните для отвечающих "сохранить в Word" — это значит создать документ с нуля или дописывать в существующий? Потому что код для каждого случая будет _совершенно разный_. И какой алгоритм работы с файлами? Одна запись — один файл или всё будете в один записывать и т.д.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ,Возможны все варианты.

Comment: А если создать ole-объект (или com, не знаю как сейчас правильно) ворда и программно скопипастить туда html? Если можно вставить форматированный текст вручную в редакторе, то должна быть и какая-то вариация функции paste у объекта автомтизации.

Comment: @Sergey, Допустим, распарил я страницу и получил строку: Т<i>Е</i>СТ. Я думаю, что она в итоге в итоге скопируется без форматирования. Тут, наверное, не все так просто.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь готовым решением. http://html2openxml.codeplex.com/. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Думать не надо. Надо посмотреть мануал и попробовать. Возможно даже в самом ворде через VBA, всего одна сточка.

Comment: OpenXML+[AltChunk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk.aspx). Тут есть пример [кода(EN SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18152334/5232946).